# Measuring iPhone application load time

Tags: iphone, optimization

I am in the process of optimizing an iPhone app for very short load time and am wondering:

Is there a means of measuring the load time of an iPhone app from the time the user taps the icon to the time that the app is usable (or at least –viewDidLoad gets called)?

Ideally this would work in the device and simulator, but if someone has found a way to measure this time exclusively in the simulator that would at least be a starting point.

And no; "stopwatch" or "one Mississippi, two Mississippi" do not count. :-)

Comment: You can't simply log the time immediately upon `applicationDidLaunch` and then log the time when `viewDidLoad` gets called?

Answer (score 2):

Start a timer in the init method of the App Delegate, and then stop when the viewDidAppear:-

Start timer with:-

```
NSDate *startTime = [NSDate date];
```

...and end with:-

```
NSTimeInterval elapsedTime = [startTime timeIntervalSinceNow];
NSLog(@"Startup tasks: %f", -elapsedTime);
```

This won't start from the moment the icon is tapped, but should be fairly early into your workings.  You could probably view an earlier time in the logs put out in the debugger console?

Answer (score 2):

As part of WWDC 2016 Apple announced a new environment variable, available as part of beta 2, which will help you to record the launch time of an application.

One issue with the answers above is they do not take into account the pre-main time, where images are loaded and rebase and binding fixups take place.

If you add the variable 
`DYLD_PRINT_STATISTICS = 1` you will get the pre-main time printed in the console.

Session 406 from WWDC 2016 goes into this variable usage and how to interpret the results.

Answer (score 1):

Put `NSLog(@"started loading");` at the beginning of applicationDidFinishLauching and `NSLog(@"finished loading");` in the viewDidAppear of the app delegate. In the debugger console you get something like

```
2010-11-21 17:16:06.278 Phy[9157:207] started loading
2010-11-21 17:16:06.301 Phy[9157:207] finished loading
```

Therefore the simulator needed 0.03 seconds to start the app.