# Measure apps loading time

Tags: android, iphone, ios, performance

I'm doing an iPhone (and possibly Android) travel apps' Benchmark for my final thesis. I'm going to analyse the userfriendliness, content, etc.. but I'd also like to measure the apps' pages loading time. I know this kind of tool exists for websites or mobile websites, but does someone know if it exists for apps?

Comment: Are you trying to measure the time it takes for the app to start, or to load data? And do you own the app or is it from the App Store?

Comment: Well, doing both would be perfect, but I'll be happy to measure only one thing.

I do not own the app... It's for a apps' benchmark, I'll take everything from the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128171/measuring-iphone-application-load-time) answer might help for a first idea.
Another way might be to use the Instruments Time Profiler. This should give you detailed analytics.